# Problem with loading schema in vscode settings.json file

Tags: java, json, visual-studio-code, javafx, schema

I have added this java classPath in the settings.json file to work with JavaFx in vscode in Ubuntu 22.04

```
"java.classPath": "/usr/share/openjfx/lib",
```

After adding this line  the error messages that Java Compiler showed me previously related to JavaFX packages and methods have disappeared. Also intellisense and suggestions for JavaFX is working.

But I am having this error messages in settings.json file

> Unable to load schema from 'vscode://schemas/settings/folder': cannot open vscode://schemas/settings/folder. Detail: Unable to resolve text model content for resource vscode://schemas/settings/folder.

my settings.json file look like this:

```
{   
    "java.classPath": "/usr/share/openjfx/lib",
    "java.project.sourcePaths": ["src"],
    "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar",
        "/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.web.jar",
        "/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.swing.jar",
        "/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.media.jar",
        "/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.graphics.jar",
        "/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.fxml.jar",
        "/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.controls.jar",
        "/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.base.jar"
    ],
    "java.debug.settings.onBuildFailureProceed": true
}
```

i tried changing schema folder by the link that I got from chatGPT and also searched some questions related to this in here. But none of them worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So your error exists in the *settins.json* file? Then why not show the complete content, and show the detailed error interface?

- The easiest way should be to restart your vscode and make sure its version and extensions are up to date.
- You can also delete the *settings.json* file and reconfigure.
- Another setting that may be relevant is the web proxy, which you can turn off by adding the following setting

```json
    "http.proxySupport": "off",
```

Comment: thanks . after adding that proxy support you mentioned the issue solved.

Comment: `proxySupport` did it for me. Why on earth would this make a difference, and why on earth would it be enabled by default.. one more reason to loathe vscode

Comment: You can add that setting to either the user settings OR the project settings via ./.vscode/settings.json, save it and see the error disappear. Then you can delete those changes and the warning stays away. Adding that setting must trigger something else that triggers something else that solves the issue indirectly.